# Navigating the webBrowser with proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to make an application in VS in C #. 
Wanted navigate in webBrowser I have on my form through proxy. 
But I can not.
With this code I can access a page by proxy.
But if I click within the page. I am already browsing by webBrowser directly without going through proxy.

```
proxyURI = new System.Uri("http://" + myProxy);
proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxyURI);
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/");
request.Proxy = proxy;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();         
receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = receiveStream;
```

To make things easier is not possible to place the proxy in the WebBrowser? 
Like:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").byProxy("MyProxy").InvokeMember("click");
```

My apology but I'm noob in C #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix `WebRequest` and `WebBrowser` in this case, they have completely different Net sessions.

Use `WebBrowser` alone, and set the proxy with `UrlMkSetSessionOption`/`INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY`. Do this before you create `WebBrowser` (Otherwise, I'm not sure if existing `WebBrowser` instance picks up new proxy settings instantly).